# Cant receive push notifications from Intercom, FCM

Tags: java, android, intercom

Having trouble with Intercom push notifications. I am unable to receive any push notifications on the device from Intercom; standard notifications sent from FCM work perfectly as expected.

Have followed [this](https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/android-fcm-push-notifications) tutorial, and have added the server key to Intercom as suggested.

**CloudMessaging.java**

```
public class CloudMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private final IntercomPushClient intercomPushClient = new IntercomPushClient();

public void getFirebaseInstanceID() {
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                            return;
                        }
                        intercomPushClient.sendTokenToIntercom(application, token);
                      );
                    }
                 }
        });
}


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Map message = remoteMessage.getData();

    if (intercomPushClient.isIntercomPush(message)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Intercom message received");
        intercomPushClient.handlePush(getApplication(), message);
    } else {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }
}
```

**manifest file**

```
    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".CloudMessaging"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: have you download the son file and located it in your app?

Comment: Hi @BitaMirshafiee; yes I have. We are receiving standard push notifications from Firebase already. Just not Intercom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one instance of `"com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"` in the Gradle file. In my case I stuck with `.CloudMessaging` as that is where the Intercom notification is handled as shown above. My `CloudMessaging` class needed to a have a public constructor with 0 input fields to open when the notification is recieved. eg.

**Gradle File**

```
<service
    android:name=".CloudMessaging"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**CloudMessaging Class**

```
 public CloudMessaging() {
        //dont delete or you wont get push notifications buddy
}

CloudMessaging(Context context, Application application) {
        this.context = context;
        this.application = application;
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(FCM_ID_SHAREDPREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
```

The next most important thing is ensure you are using the correct Intercom SDK. I had originally implemented a 'base' sdk that did not have push notification capability. Make sure you have the full sdk.

**Bad SDK**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:x.x.+'
}
```

**Good SDK**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:x.x.+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:x.+' 
}
```